# Using maxcpucount to parallelise unit testing in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild, nunit

In a particular SOA-styled application I'm working on we have a large number of unit tests in each service. The tests for each service run serially, and I want to test running the tests for each service in parallel.

In our msbuild file is the following:

```
<Target Name="RunUnitTests">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'@(UnitTestsOutput)' == ''">
        <UnitTestsOutput Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\**\*Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutput, ' ')" />
</Target>
```

So all tests project assemblies end with the name "Tests", thus they get found/picked up with that search.
Would it be possible/feasible to do something like this?

```
<Target Name="RunUnitTests">
    <ItemGroup Condition="'@(UnitTestsOutput)' == ''">
        <UnitTestsOutputService1 Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service1*\*Tests.dll" />
        <UnitTestsOutputService2 Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service2*\*Tests.dll" />
        <UnitTestsOutputService3 Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service3*\*Tests.dll" />
        <UnitTestsOutputService4 Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service4*\*Tests.dll" />
        <UnitTestsOutputService5 Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service5*\*Tests.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService1, ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService2, ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService3, ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService4, ' ')" />
    <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService5, ' ')" />
</Target>
```

And then if the build is run using /maxcpucount it could possibly parallelise those sets of tests?

Answer (score 2):

You can use BuildInParallel = true and a custom target:

```
<Project .... DefaultTargets="RunAll" />
...
    <Target Name="RunSingle">
        <ItemGroup>
            <UnitTestsOutputService Include="$(UnitTestsOutputFolder)\*Service$(ServiceNum)*\*Tests.dll" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Exec Command="$(NUnitRunner) /nologo /labels /timeout=30000 @(UnitTestsOutputService , ' ')" />
    </Target>

    <ItemGroup>
     <Parallel Include="1;2;3;4;5" />
    <ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="RunAll">

     <ItemGroup>
      <Projects Include="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" > <-- for recursive call to same build file -->
       <Properties>ServiceNum=%(parallel.identity)</Properties> <-- Service1, Service2 .. -->
      </Projects>
     </ItemGroup>
     <MSBuild Projects="@(Projects)" BuildInParallel="true" Targets="RunSingle" />
    </Target>
```